# Create assets subfolder on upload based on entry field value?

Tags: assets

I have a projects section on my website, there can be multiple projects from one client. Each project has at least one image.

I wanted to know if it is possible when uploading assets to a new project entry to be able to create a new subfolder within my specified assets folder for that particular client?

So can I either:

a) Create a subfolder when uploading assets.
b) Use the value of the "client" field to dynamically create a subfolder when uploading images to the entry.

Any help/direction this would be appreciated.

Jay

Comment: Never mind, n00b moment - figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's totally possible, you just need to set your asset field to upload all assets to a single folder and then you can set a sub-folder path that's created dynamically. (→ [Restricting Uploads to a Single Folder](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#restricting-uploads-to-a-single-folder)).

In your case that path would be something like this:

```
assets/images/projects/{{ object.client.first().friendlyName }}
```

or with fallback to a default sub-folder:

```
{{ object.client.first()|length ? object.client.first().friendlyName : 'Other' }}
```